# Radio check/uncheck in mvc 4 razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, radio-button

I'm trying to make the radio button checked based on the `roleId` in the ViewBag but no matter what the value is the radio button is always checked.
Here is the razor :

```
<input type="radio" id="rdResident" class="userType" checked="@(ViewBag.roleId=="5"?"checked":"false")" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need the word "checked". Try...

```
<input type="radio" id="rdResident" class="userType" @(ViewBag.roleId==5 ? "checked" : "") />
```